# Why is *mut i8 used for the type of WINDOW in ncurses-rs?

Tags: types, rust

Given [this definition in the ncurses-rs crate](https://github.com/jeaye/ncurses-rs/blob/59fbbc6456dcd87d29a7761576723dab0c08986b/src/ll.rs#L35):

```
pub type WINDOW = *mut i8;
```

A [usage of `WINDOW`](https://github.com/jeaye/ncurses-rs/blob/59fbbc6456dcd87d29a7761576723dab0c08986b/src/ll.rs#L186):

```
pub fn newwin(_:c_int,_:c_int,_:c_int,_:c_int) -> WINDOW;
```

and the implementation, in the ncurses C library ([1](https://github.com/mirror/ncurses/blob/89175dffb0245ffaa1ffec80373cb9990f8dc7fe/include/curses.h.in#L372), [2](https://github.com/mirror/ncurses/blob/89175dffb0245ffaa1ffec80373cb9990f8dc7fe/include/curses.h.in#L421), [3](https://github.com/mirror/ncurses/blob/89175dffb0245ffaa1ffec80373cb9990f8dc7fe/include/curses.h.in#L721)):

```
// 1:
typedef struct _win_st WINDOW;
// 2:
struct _win_st { 
    /* lots of fields... */
};
// 3: 
(WINDOW *) newwin (int,int,int,int);
```

Why is the type of `WINDOW` `*mut i8`?

I am reading that as a pointer to a C `char`, which is obviously not correct. Is it best practice to simply say a pointer is of type `i8` if you aren't implementing the C struct in Rust? Does it not matter at all what type that is?

Comment: I guess this is to mimic `void*` (which Rust does not have), because the content of `WINDOW` never matters and `WINDOW`s always are manipulated through a pointer.

Comment: @mcarton you mean like the `c_void` type that is [just a bit higher up in the same source file](https://github.com/jeaye/ncurses-rs/blob/59fbbc6456dcd87d29a7761576723dab0c08986b/src/ll.rs#L14)? ^_^

Comment: @Shepmaster so it looks like unlike me the author knew about `c_void` :p. It'd better be a new dedicated type anyway. Nice answer, as always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless an author of that project happens to stroll past, you won't get an authoritative answer.

As [mcarton points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681209/why-mut-i8-in-ncurses-rs-c-library-wrapper#comment66662763_39681209), you'd normally reach for a `void *` in C to represent a reference to an opaque struct. The authors could have just as easily done

```
pub type WINDOW = *mut c_void;
```

With this change, the code still compiles.

However, there's a better option. As [the documentation says](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ffi.html#representing-opaque-structs):

> To do this in Rust, let’s create our own opaque types with `enum`:
>
> ```
> pub enum Foo {}
> pub enum Bar {}
>
> extern "C" {
>     pub fn foo(arg: *mut Foo);
>     pub fn bar(arg: *mut Bar);
> }
> ```
>
> By using an `enum` with no variants, we create an opaque type that we
>   can’t instantiate, as it has no variants. But because our `Foo` and `Bar`
>   types are different, we’ll get type safety between the two of them, so
>   we cannot accidentally pass a pointer to `Foo` to `bar()`.

In this case, it could look like:

```
pub enum Window {}
pub type WINDOW = *mut Window;
```

Again, the library still compiles with this change.

Comment: Wow, I completely missed that part of the documentation that directly answers my question :) Thank you.